# Using MongoDb Realm authentication within a React app

Tags: mongodb, http, realm

I am learning MongoDb Realm from the documentation and following the examples given. My code to login is

```
const loginEmailPassword = async (email, password) => {

    const app = Realm.App.getApp(APP_ID)

    const credentials = Realm.Credentials.emailPassword(email, password)
    try {
        // Authenticate the user
        const user = await app.logIn(credentials)

        return true
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Failed to log in', err)
    }
    return false
}
```

If the credentials match a current user all is good, if the don't it doesn't throw an error but generates the following in the console:

> POST https://eu-west-1.aws.stitch.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/<"my Realm App ID">/auth/providers/local-userpass/login 401
> Failed to log in Error: Request failed (POST https://eu-west-1.aws.stitch.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/<"my Realm App ID">/auth/providers/local-userpass/login): invalid username/password (status 401)

Can anyone please help me understand what is going on?

Comment: A couple of things; why are you returning true in the try block instead of the user? See [Email Auth](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/examples/authenticate-users/#email-password-user)? second thing; have you verified the APP_ID is correct for this app? Third thing; in the Realm Console->Realm->Your App->Authentication do you have emal/password authentication activated? Oh, and check the logs in the Realm app section to see if you're actually hitting the server.

Comment: Thanks. I was returning user but changed it to true/false for simplicity whilst testing. I can login using the correct email/password so both points 2 and 3 do work, I just wanted to trap the error for when the user credentials were incorrect? Many thanks

Comment: The logs tell me I have... Invalid Password Error Jul 17 10:37:47+01:00 12ms Authentication login local-userpass

Comment: What happens if you remove `return false` and change `return true` to `return user` - try that with both a valid password and invalid and see if it makes a difference